# Is "afx_msg" necessary for message handler function?

Tags: c++, mfc, handler, message

I used to add `"afx_msg"` prefix at declaration of `message handler function`.
But I found `the function` still called whithout `the prefix`.
Is `"afx_msg"` nessary?
Added:

```
class CVLManageDlg : public CDialog  
{    ...
protected:   
    void OnAdd();
    void OnModify();
    void OnDel();
}


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CVLManageDlg, CDialog)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_ADD_VL_MANAGE, OnAdd)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_MD_VL_MANAGE, OnModify)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_DEL_VL_MANAGE, OnDel)
    ON_NOTIFY(NM_CLICK, IDC_LIST_VL_MANAGE, OnClickList)
    ON_WM_SIZE()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void CVLManageDlg::OnAdd()
{...}

void CVLManageDlg::OnModify()
{...}

void CVLManageDlg::OnDel()
{...}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ClassWizard requires that you use the afx_msg keyword in your message map handler declarations.

And [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0812b0wa%28VS.80%29.aspx)